# CAS server work fine on Tomcat but not work on Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, cas, weblogic12c

I've some issues to make CAS Server work with WebLogic 12c although it work fine with Tomcat. Before deploy on Weblogic, I follow this guide : https://github.com/gentics/Gentics-SSO-CAS/wiki/Oracle-Weblogic-Configuration  add file weblogic.xml in Webcontent/WEB-INF/ with content :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<wls:weblogic-version>10.3</wls:weblogic-version>
<wls:context-root>cas</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>
</wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>`

and use quartz-1.5.2.jar
This is logs of Weblogic 12c:
- org.springframework.webflow.execution.FlowExecutionException: Exception thrown in state 'viewLoginForm' of flow 'login'
- Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception resolving view with name 'casLoginView' 
- Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'casSamlServiceSuccessView': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jasig.cas.web.view.Saml10SuccessResponseView 
- Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jasig.cas.web.view.Saml10SuccessResponseView

I have no clue how to fix this. If you have any idea it would be nice. Thanks,

Comment: Where did you put your quartz-1.5.2.jar lib ?

Comment: I declare in pom.xml :))

Answer (score 1):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is usually caused by conflicting/missing JARs. Examine the runtime to see if Saml10SuccessResponseView is properly loaded and installed.